# Retrieve data from multiple models

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I've got a blog-post-editor.

The blog-post I'm editing is the model.
Now I'd need all categories for the blog-post stored in a select-box.

What's the best way to retrieve and display those categories?

Currently I'd do it like this in the controller but they are about to be deprecated in Ember 2.0:

```
categories: function() {
  return this.get('store').find('category');
}.property()
```

Comment: categories: function() {
return this.store.all('category');
}.property('model')

Comment: This way I'd have all categories in the model but the model is already occupied by the current post I'm editing.

Comment: the above code you need to add in controller.. the model(editing post) you will get from the route.. as according to convention, we get model from the route and the extra things you can get from controller.. so just add it in controller.. am not fully aware of your requirement, so it will be great if you can more details so that i could help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your blog-posts route, you can override `setupController(controller, model)` to retrieve the categories and set them as a property on your controller, e.g.:

```
App.BlogPostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function (controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);
    controller.set('categories', this.store.find('category'));
  }
});
```